# php include css vs html link css (effects to server and user experience)

Tags: php, css, http, server, user-experience

Is it a good idea to using `<?php include "main.css.php"; ?>` instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">`? From server resource (will it makes my server heavier) and user experience (page loading time) point of view. **The main angle here is will php include css download multiple times as opposing to html link, or will they both only have to download one time (http request one time).**

P.S.
Initially, I am doing this because by using php I can give custom colors and other settings a name, so I don't have to using class name for html (ever put multiple class names in lots of html elements? The readability is a pain). Later on, I can make my css dynamic, which lead me to do lots of powerful stuff. The advantage goes on.

Comment: Sass is a much nicer and more elegant approach instead of trying to build css from php

Comment: Well, I heard about Sass and Less. And they achieve the same thing as I am using PHP. Sass is written in Ruby. And I am using PHP to manipulate css. Ruby and PHP are kind of on the same level programming languages anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good to use such practice
But if you want you can use this 
Make your css file main.php
`<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>
body{ margin:0px; font:9px/11px "Tahoma", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#010000; 
background:#f3f6e1 url(<?php echo base_url().'public/';?>images/body_bg_1.gif) repeat-x 0 0}`

And include it in the page where you want

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.php" media="screen"> 
</head>`

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try your method out. But I really wanna know how http treat php include and html link differently. To my understanding, they are both external files, but php include is similar to internal css.

Comment: Thanks, It works great. I am sensing maybe it's not a good practice by using php include for css. That's why I came here to post this question. Please enlighten me the why.

Comment: mixing two different world will be very harmful. It can create some un necessary output to your program.